# Speeding-up the Apple review process for iOS application for patches and hotfixes

Tags: ios, itunes, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Is there any way to upload a quick-fix for my application, approved by Apple some days ago? Or should I wait for another 2 weeks for re-review again?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's app review process and not directly about programming or coding.

Comment: @Pang this question is 5 years old and was viewed 20,000 times and helped a lot of people. But who cares, please go on.

Comment: @FelixSFD I believe that when you develop for iOS, you are not doing it for pure fun. Thus quick-patching IS a part of development cycle for iOS platform. BTW, this question is almost 6 years old, why now?

Comment: @WASD42 We are currently [burninating the Apple-tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333833/4687348). That's why we came across this question.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If you need to push a *critical* bug-fix to AppStore (either Mac or iOS), you may ask Apple for an **Expedited Review Process**. You may do so here: [Request an Expedited App Review](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/appreviewteam/)

Comment: @WASD42 did you get an expedited review? Weather or not they did, did they give a reason?

Comment: You will usually get an expedited review if you request it, but you only have a limited amount of them available, so don't expedite all your changes :-) We had an expedited review go through within one day

Answer (score 12):

Besides using the [Apple expedited review process](https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/app-review/), you can install [Rollout.io SDK](https://www.rollout.io), Rollout.io allows to hot-patch your production application and actually fix and contain quality issues in production without having to go through the app store.

Disclosure: I'm one of the founders of Rollout.io

Answer (score 2):

You can request an expedited app review for two reasons:`Urgent Bug Fix` or `Time-Sensitive Event`. It was written at [App Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-review/).

> Expedited App Review
>   If you face extenuating circumstances, you can request the review of your app to be expedited. These circumstances include fixing a critical bug in your app on the App Store or releasing your app to coincide with an event you are directly associated with.
>
> Urgent Bug Fix
>   If you've submitted an update to fix a critical bug in your app on the App Store and you are requesting an expedited review, be sure to include the steps to reproduce the bug on the current version of your app.
>
> Time-Sensitive Event
>   For apps associated with an event, we recommend you plan and schedule the release of your app in iTunes Connect. However, if your app is still in review and the launch of your event is quickly approaching, you can request to have your app review expedited. When submitting your request, it's important to include the event, date of the event, and your app's association with the event.
>
> Please Note: Expedited reviews are granted on a limited basis and we cannot guarantee that every request will be expedited.

Answer (score 0):

Any change you make needs to be approved by Apple before it's allowed into the App Store so unfortunately you'll have to wait. I've found the review times to be about a week for updates but your mileage may vary

Answer (score 0):

An update usually takes approximately the same time as an original release. It seems Apple reviews each submission as if it were a new application. All approx 8 of our apps have been like this